# Opening and saving .docx files s with LibreOffice 5 creates files that cannot be opened by Microsoft office users

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-office

I'm using LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 and have problems with .docx-files. When opening a .docx-file everything appears normal but it has no title (the window bar shows "Untitled 1 - LibreOffice Writer"). After renaming and sending the files I've heard from other people that they cannot open this document. This happened with .docx files as well as .xlsx files.

Sure, I can save files in .doc but I wonder what causes this behaviour. A previous installation of LibreOffice 3 didn't do this and I had almost no problem exchanging documents with Microsoft Office users.

Is there any fix?

Comment: Would PDF be an applicable format to send your documents in?

Comment: @luk3yx Unfortunately not. I have to exchange documents various times with several people and everybody has to add something. It would be much more comfortable to send out the documents as is without converting it every time to .doc and hope that formatting stays the same.

Comment: LibreOffice Writer can process Windows compatible *.docx files. Check these possible culprits:  First, you can check if the problem is with your personal configuration or settings by logging in as Guest (which will always have a default configuration).  Then try to process a compatible *.docx file from that account.  If that succeeds, then the culprit is your personal configuration.  If fails, then purge your current LibreOffice installation and reinstall it to check the install integrity.  You can share the files between your guest account and normal account using Dropbox or Google Drive.